# Postgresql - restore SQL dump with tablespaces

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, backup-strategies

I'm planning to move some tables to **different tablespaces (folders)** on my PROD Linux box.
Overnight DB backups are done using **pg_dumpall**

I have also DEV environment working under Windows OS Im usually restoring sql dump (made on Linux).
Im worrying now how to restore such sql dumps, having pointers to Linux partition, in Linux notation.

I read on various webpages that same folder structure has to be created in order to restore non-standard tablespaces. But folder paths in Windows and Linux looks totally different (c:\... vs /opt/...)

Is there any command line switch allowing remap tablespace to other (Windows-like location) during restore? If not how you guys manage that scenario ?

I guess I shoud be able to archieve that by editing this SQL dump file - but it's huge, few hundred gigs file, also it is a bit problematic to automate

Comment: Why are you tablespaces to begin with? They are rarely needed anyway.

Comment: Reason is DB space usage. I would like to move historical data tables to slower / less expensive disk volume, and keep the other piece on fast SSDs

Comment: For development, it is IMHO good enough/better to put everthing on slow (magnetic) disks. (or: slower hardware: I am currently developing with the DB on a RaspberryPi ;-) [but I would *never* put it on a Windows machine. I'm not that masochistic! ]

Comment: wildplasser - my app has to work on different environments (Linux and Windows too). So far I had no issues with that. My only question here is backup / restore process

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the actual tablespace definitions with a separate `pg_dumpall` command. You still need to do some editing, but the output is not that large. (similar for users)

---

```
pg_dumpall --tablespaces-only mydatabasename >stuff.out
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to remap tablespace names during import, so you will need to create them in your Windows installation with the same name - the actual location physical location ("folder structure") is irrelevant  as the SQL dump only references them by name.

If the script contains the `create tablespace` command you need to change *that* command to use a directory/path name that exists on your system before you can run the SQL script. But you only need to change that, all other places will refer to the tablespace name, not the folder path.

Typically pg_dump is easier than pg_dumpall for moving databases around (e.g. because of tablespaces).